Amazon Linux 2023 set up sftp for several users
I have an app that receives data files from users. Each user should only have access to their "upload" folder.
i.e. data/user1, data/user2, data/user3.
What is the best way to set this up?
Do I need to have a each user in a separate group?
Can I have a group of users and then user1, user2, user3?
What is the best practice for authentication?
How can I create a pem file for each user?

And, if "PEM file" is about certificate auth, that's a right thing to do, then man ssh-keygen.

Thanks for the response.   This does answer my question.
